# high-available Infrastructure CI/CD pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, high-availability, infrastructure-as-code

I'm interested in IaC's continuous deployment and continuous integration. As we need to ensure the infrastructure is ready to be deployed for production, my initiation thinking was to have separate environments for dev and prod. But the point that I'm a little bit hesitant to consider it as a problem or usual stuff is about the cost efficiency of this idea. Because we are running the infrastructure exactly twice, the infrastructure cost will double.

Is this usual to have two separate and identical infrastructure for dev and prod?
Or is there any working solution that makes the continuous integration for infrastructure considering high availability and high resiliency more cost-efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! having a separate setup for each environment is highly recommended. So you will have a more visible workflow between different environments. But do you need to manage identical setup for dev and prod? Please No. You can keep your dev setup at a minimum. Yes, It will cost some bucks, but it will help you to keep your production bug-free and save more money, and time that you will have to put on troubleshooting.